# Database deadlock and TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, deadlock

The following is my code that opens a transaction and inserts a row to the table, meanwhile I open another connection and query the same table. The program hangs up at Line (*).

```
//TestTable is empty.
using (connection1 == new SqlConnection(OpConsoleLib.std.CONNECTIONSTRING)) {
    connection1.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into TestTable values('hello')", connection1);
    cmd.Transaction = connection1.BeginTransaction();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(OpConsoleLib.std.CONNECTIONSTRING)) {
        connection2.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from TestTable where name='hello'", connection2); //(*)

        int count=Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());

    }

    cmd.Transaction.Commit();
}
```

TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL is `ReadCommitted` on my database. I was expecting `count=0`.

It looks like connection 1 locks the table so connection 2 cannot read it. If that's true, why is there TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a first connection that opens a transaction, inserts a new row into a table, and **doesn't commit**. It has any number and variety of non-shareable locks on that table.

You then have a second connection that attempts to read the count.

Yes, this will deadlock (at the app layer, not at the SQL layer). Those connections are completely unrelated (unless you have an ambient `TransactionScope` that you haven't mentioned), so the second connection **will** be blocked. It can't tell you the count until the commit, *because it is `ReadCommitted`* - which means it can only read *committed* data. Until then: it needs to wait.

If you explicitly want to read *past* the lock, use a lower isolation level such as `READ UNCOMMITTED`, or add an explicit `NOLOCK` hint.

Comment: Oh, I found https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173763.aspx. Will  `SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON` solve the deadlock?

Comment: @LoveRight that's ... not a good way to fix a deadlock. IMO there are 3 *good* ways to fix this: 1) perform the count on the same connection as the transaction is using (this will give you the new count); 2) restructure the code so that you *don't do this* - leaving a transaction open here is a very bad smell - but if your need to wait (to get the reliable value) - then *wait*; 3) if you *must* read past the lock, use a lower isolation; snapshot might solve this, but for reasons that basically scream "I don't understand what is going on" - which is never good

Comment: I'm just doing experiments. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's defined behaviour of READ_COMMITED isolaction level.

Have a look at the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Read_committed