# Handling concurrent transactions in two different servers

Tags: sql-server, rest, concurrency

I have a requirement of implementing a windows service which calls the REST services from the other application in real time and process that the response. The goal of the windows service are -

1. The windows service has to pull records in a batch of 100 from SQL server 
   data base.
2. Construct the request and call the REST API.
3. Once the response is received update the status and process the response and 
   update in the data base.

This current state is working without any issues till now, Now due to the increased load we have to place another instance of the same service in another server. As the two instances are running parallel I need to know the following,  Please let me know if any suggestions-

1. How to make sure that the same records are not sent to call the REST API 
   again and again.
2. What is the best way to handle the concurrency in this case.

Thanks in adavance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to handle this problem on the first layer which is the getting records from your sql database.

In your Application code, get the records with in a locked scope and flag them as isprocessing. (You can add a column for this purpose).
Your application should get the records which IsProcessing value is false.

Comment: when you say locked scope are you talking about shared lock? Not sure how to handle in multi server environment for lock.

Comment: You have two applications that try to read rows in a single database. First application (in a first server) makes a request to database to read some rows, then it will flag them as IsProcessing. While first application is inprogress, if the second application tries to reach database, it have to wait first applications' commit. You can make this with IsolationLevel of database. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36211341/database-deadlock-and-transaction-isolation-level will help you, I think